# Extra characters added to beginning of string?

Tags: c

I have two extra characters being added to the beginning of my string and I can't seem to find out why. The characters don't even appear in the code. I'm at a loss here. This is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *chars;

char* vector(char input, char *newlist);

int main(){

    char *input, *out = "Input: ";

    printf("Enter characters: ");                   
    while(1){
        char i = getchar();                         //get input
        if(i == '\n'){
            break;                                  //detect a return key
        } else{
            input = vector(i, input);               //call vector
        }
    }

    char * print = (char *)malloc(1 + strlen(input) + strlen(out));
    strcpy(print, out);                             //concat the strings
    strcat(print, input);

    printf("\n%s", print);                          //print array

    free(print);
    free(input);
    free(chars);

    return 0;                                       //exit
}

char* vector(char in, char *newlist){

    int length = strlen(newlist);                   //determine length of newlist(input)

    chars = (char*)calloc(length+2, sizeof(char));  //allocate more memory
    strcpy(chars, newlist);                         //copy the array to chars
    chars[length] = in;                             //appened new character
    chars[length + 1] = '\0';                       //append end character

    return chars;
}
```

For some reason, the code produces this:

```
Enter characters: gggg

Input: PEgggg
```

When it should be producing this:

```
Enter characters: gggg

Input: gggg
```

Comment: What does `input` point to?

Comment: Side note: since `chars` is a global variable, there is no point in `return chars;`.

Comment: @barakmanos it would be better to remove the global variable and have it local to `vector`

Comment: @M.M: I most certainly agree on that. There doesn't seem to be any point in allocating this variable globally.

Comment: You need to declare a string somewhere, like `char str[80];`

Comment: char *input is not initialized before use

Comment: Read: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You passed uninitialized `input` to `vector()` and used it, so you invoked *undefined behavior*.

Try changing `char *input` to `char *input = ""`.

Also remove `free(chars);`, or you will encounter double-free problem.

Comment: There is also a memory leak with the `calloc`d memory in vector.

Comment: Another issue is that the memory allocated by `calloc` is never freed. The best way to do this will be for `vector` to call `free(newlist)`  ; so the initial value of `input` needs to either be `calloc(1,1);` , or `NULL` with `vector()` having a special case to handle null input.

Answer (score 6):

All the points @MikeCat are said are correct, just to add that the memory allocated by `calloc` is not freed which leads to a memory leak. You can `free` it as said by @M.M in a comment, but for next time, to avoid memory leaks, you can use `valgrind`:

> Let's take your program, as `hash.c`. Got to the command line and compile it, for eg :
>
> ```
> gcc hash.c -Wall
> ```
>
> If your program compiles successfully, an executable or `out` file will appear. As we have not specified the name of the executable, it's default name will be `a.out`. So let's run it with [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/):
>
> ```
> valgrind -- leak-check=full ./a.out
> ```
>
> This will run executable, along with valgrind, and if there is a memory leak, it will show it when the executable ends.
>
> ---
>
> If you do not have [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) installed, you can install it from [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.install.html).

Answer (score 5):

I think you have one or more uninitialized fields.  I get these warnings when I try to compile:

```
$ clang -Weverything vector.c 
vector.c:15:18: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'int' to 'char' [-Wconversion]
        char i = getchar();                         //get input
             ~   ^~~~~~~~~
vector.c:19:31: warning: variable 'input' may be uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
            input = vector(i, input);               //call vector
                              ^~~~~
vector.c:11:16: note: initialize the variable 'input' to silence this warning
    char *input, *out = "Input: ";
               ^
                = NULL
vector.c:40:33: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-conversion]
    chars = (char*)calloc(length+2, sizeof(char));  //allocate more memory
                   ~~~~~~ ~~~~~~^~
vector.c:38:18: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    int length = strlen(newlist);                   //determine length of newlist(input)
        ~~~~~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
vector.c:5:7: warning: no previous extern declaration for non-static variable 'chars' [-Wmissing-variable-declarations]
char *chars;
      ^
5 warnings generated.
```

When I use ASan<sup>[what is ASan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer)?</sup>  , I get the following error:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 | ./a.out 
Enter characters: 
=================================================================
==23718==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: attempting double-free on 0x60200000ef70 in thread T0:
    #0 0x4a5f4b in free /home/development/llvm/3.7.0/final/llvm.src/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:30:3
    #1 0x4cd631 in main (/home/brian/src/so/a.out+0x4cd631)
    #2 0x7f3b94ef5a3f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x20a3f)
    #3 0x4174c8 in _start (/home/brian/src/so/a.out+0x4174c8)

0x60200000ef70 is located 0 bytes inside of 7-byte region [0x60200000ef70,0x60200000ef77)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x4a5f4b in free /home/development/llvm/3.7.0/final/llvm.src/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:30:3
    #1 0x4cd5fa in main (/home/brian/src/so/a.out+0x4cd5fa)
    #2 0x7f3b94ef5a3f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x20a3f)

previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x4a63b4 in calloc /home/development/llvm/3.7.0/final/llvm.src/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:56:3
    #1 0x4cd67c in vector (/home/brian/src/so/a.out+0x4cd67c)
    #2 0x4cd57b in main (/home/brian/src/so/a.out+0x4cd57b)
    #3 0x7f3b94ef5a3f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x20a3f)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: double-free /home/development/llvm/3.7.0/final/llvm.src/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:30:3 in free
==23718==ABORTING
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialization of the char * is missing and hence leading to undefined behavior. Pls initialize the char *

Answer (score 0):

You need delete free(print) and assign to pointers.First called double free,and last caused core dumped.I work on ubuntu and my gcc version is 4.8.4